# Xtext - eCore model, serializer can't find the model to import

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend, ecore

I have created a eCore model, and want to use Xtext with it. The model is called TransformationQueryLanguageModel.
So I create a Xtext project from my existing model. I have configured the model as a Xtext model.
However, when i generate my Dsl with the GenerateMyDsl.mwe2, it creates the correct folders and files, but it contains errors.

In the MyDslSemanticSequencer it cannot import the model.
[As you can see, it cannot resolve the imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aEc6.png)

I have tried a lot of things, trying to configure the project setup etc. But I cannot get it to work.

Can someone help?

Comment: first make sure you have the java classes generated (genmodel, generate model code) . can you check the metamodel projects manifest if it exports the package (runtime tab) and the dsls manifest if it requires the metamodel project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.